# Bing Map implementation

Tags: bing-maps, bing

I am  not familiar the **bing Map**

I need to display the us map for a given zip code,in a page

How can i  do this

Can anyone help me please

Comment: What is the platform? Ajax or Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at their API reference...

- [AJAX Control Version 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx)
- [AJAX Control Version 6.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429619.aspx)

You will need to geocode the zip code first; if you only need to do this once to display a static map, then you can use [this](http://www.batchgeo.com/lookup/) site, although there are lots of other free sites online that do the same thing.  Once you have your lat/lon it's pretty straightforward to use them to center your map object.

```
// assume that lat, lon, and map are js variables you have already declared and set
var oLatLon = new VELatLong(lat, lon);
map.PanToLatLong(oLatLon);
```

If the map needs to be dynamic and you'll have to geocode addresses on the fly, then I'm not sure what the best approach is.  I think there are databases that contain all zipcodes & their corresponding lat/lon coordinates available for download.  It might also be worth checking out the [Bing MapPoints SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427712.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's easy using REST services which ship with Bing Api. [Here](http://asprogramming.blogspot.com/2012/03/bing-map-multiple-pushpin-addition-part.html) you can find a blog post with thorough description.